# Apple Watch: Heart Rate and Cardiogram Not Updating

Tags: apple-watch

The Heart Rate and Cardiogram apps on my Apple Watch Series 1 stopped working the day after I updated my iPhone SE to iOS 12.2. Might there be a connection?

The LED sensors on the back of the watch are not lit. I have tried the troubleshooting steps with no success. How do I get these apps working again?

Comment: When you say “the troubleshooting steps” - what specifically are you doing? Also which cardiogram app on series 1 hardware is being used?  We might need to know the watchOS version as well. And add it to the question above to provide all those details might help someone help you.

Comment: I have had success fixing issues like this (but not this one, haven’t seen it) rebooting both the iPhone & the watch.